# Endeca 11.2 workbench audit log

Tags: log4j, endeca, endeca-workbench

I am trying to log all workbench activity like experience manager changes, thesaurus changes etc. I have enabled webstudio audit.

```
### webstudio auditing
log4j.logger.com.endeca.etools.webstudio.audit=ALL, auditfile
log4j.additivity.com.endeca.etools.webstudio.audit=true
```

But what is logged in webstudio_audit.log is just login tries related information.

What is the proper configuration in order to achieve the above result?

Comment: Audit log does not show much information except who is logged in and made some changes.

Comment: Hi Ajay thanks for your answer. Is there any oob configuration that can provide such information? I can see that in webstudio.properties there is configuration about emails. Can this be activated and used for this?

Comment: Hi Ajay. FYI from documentation: Audit log for activity such as dynamic business rule and search configuration changes. Logging for rules webstudio_audit.log includes the name of the rule being modified, when it was modified, who modified it (based on Endeca Workbench user name), and any note associated with the change

Comment: I have not seen all those info in audit logs, I see below 6.09.2017 08:48:22.497 *INFO* [Thread-6202] com.endeca.etools.webstudio.audit User: admin has logged in successfully. Let me know if you can see other details in logs.